# PHP: Split a string at the first period that isn't the decimal point in a price or the last character of the string

Tags: php, regex, string, split, format

I want to split a string as per the parameters laid out in the title. I've tried a few different things including using preg_match with not much success so far and I feel like there may be a simpler solution that I haven't clocked on to.

I have a regex that matches the "price" mentioned in the title (see below).

`/(?=.)\£(([1-9][0-9]{0,2}(,[0-9]{3})*)|[0-9]+)?(\.[0-9]{1,2})?/`

And here are a few example scenarios and what my desired outcome would be:

Example 1:

```
input: "This string should not split as the only periods that appear are here £19.99 and also at the end."
output: n/a
```

Example 2:

```
input: "This string should split right here. As the period is not part of a price or at the end of the string."
output: "This string should split right here"
```

Example 3:

```
input: "There is a price in this string £19.99, but it should only split at this point. As I want it to ignore periods in a price"
output: "There is a price in this string £19.99, but it should only split at this point"
```

Comment: Can you come up with some examples that clearly show input and output? Your current examples are ambiguous at best.

Comment: Edited to make it a bit clearer.

Comment: Is using [explode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)('. ', $yourString) *(Note the space after the dot)* not an option? Do you have to exactly verify its a price? You could in theory use explode and check if its [count](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) is more than 1 if so use the first part otherwise return your `"n/a"`

Comment: Using regex to split into sentences is the wrong tool (inappropriate and not flexible). You should use intlBreakIterator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using

```php
preg_split('~\£(?:[1-9]\d{0,2}(?:,\d{3})*|[0-9]+)?(?:\.\d{1,2})?(*SKIP)(*F)|\.(?!\s*$)~u', $string)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/GFkoer/1).

The pattern matches your pattern, `\£(?:[1-9]\d{0,2}(?:,\d{3})*|[0-9]+)?(?:\.\d{1,2})?` and *skips* it with `(*SKIP)(*F)`, else, it matches a non-final `.` with `\.(?!\s*$)` (even if there is trailing whitespace chars).

If you really only need to split on the first occurrence of the qualifying dot you can use a matching approach:

```php
preg_match('~^((?:\£(?:[1-9]\d{0,2}(?:,\d{3})*|[0-9]+)?(?:\.\d{1,2})?|[^.])+)\.(.*)~su', $string, $match)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/GFkoer/2). Here,

- `^` - matches a string start position
- `((?:\£(?:[1-9]\d{0,2}(?:,\d{3})*|[0-9]+)?(?:\.\d{1,2})?|[^.])+)` - one or more occurrences of your currency pattern or any one char other than a `.` char
- `\.` - a `.` char
- `(.*)` - Group 2: the rest of the string.

Answer (score 1):

To split a text into sentences avoiding the different pitfalls like dots or thousand separators in numbers and some abbreviations (like `etc.`), the best tool is [`intlBreakIterator`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.intlbreakiterator.php) designed to deal with natural language:

```
$str = 'There is a price in this string £19.99, but it should only split at this point. As I want it to ignore periods in a price';

$si = IntlBreakIterator::createSentenceInstance('en-US');
$si->setText($str);
$si->next();

echo substr($str, 0, $si->current());
```

`IntlBreakIterator::createSentenceInstance` returns an iterator that gives the indexes of the different sentences in the string.

It takes in account `?`, `!` and `...` too. In addition to numbers or prices pitfalls, it works also well with this kind of string:

```
$str = 'John Smith, Jr. was running naked through the garden crying "catch me! catch me!", but no one was chasing him. His psychatre looked at him from the window with a circumspect eye.';
```

More about rules used by `IntlBreakIterator` [here](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr29/#Sentence_Boundaries).

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use this regex:

`\.` 
Since you only have a space after the first sentence (and not a price), this should work just as well, right?